# nginx load balancing - do I have to have multiple copies of my API?

Tags: api, nginx, parse-server

I want to load balance my Parse API using NGINX

My API runs currently on nginx on one server, if I want to load balance it, do I have to host my API on every host ?

I want it to look like this

```
----------                             /----- [ api-0.myhost.com ]
| client | --------> [ api.myhost.com ] ----- [ api-1.myhost.com ]
----------                             \----- [ api-2.myhost.com ]
```

In this case do I have to install nginx and deploy my API to very `api-X.myhost.com` ?

Or I just deploy my API on `api.myhost.com` and on the `api-X.myhost.com` I just install nginx ?

Comment: Do you really need LB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just install nginx on api.host.com, then configure nginx for load balancing as below:

```
upstream api-app {
              least_conn;
              server api-0.myhost.com:port weight=1 max_fails=1;
              server api-2.myhost.com:port weight=1 max_fails=1;
              server api-3.myhost.com:port weight=1 max_fails=1;   

        }

        server {
              listen 80;
              listen  443 ssl;
              server_name api.myhost.com;



              ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/api_ssl-bundle.crt;
              ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/api_com.key;

              client_max_body_size 2000M;
              large_client_header_buffers 32 128k;
              location / {
               proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                proxy_buffers 64 128k;
                proxy_buffer_size 256k;
                proxy_pass http://api-app;
                proxy_connect_timeout   1200;
                proxy_send_timeout      1200;
                proxy_read_timeout      1200;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
              }
        }
```

With `port` is a port which your api-app listen on its host.

Comment: do I have to install nginx and have copy of my API on `api-0.myhost.com ... api-2.myhost.com` ?

Comment: do I have to open the `port` that my api listen too, if i use private ips in the upstream?

Comment: if 4 hosts are in the same VPC (subnet) , you can use private ip address(LAN ip address) , if 4 hosts are seperated 4 other servers, you can use firewall to filter ip address to allow or deny to access hosts by api post

Comment: `do I have to open the port that my api listen too, if i use private ips in the upstream? ` yes, make sure from api can connect to api-X hosts by ports